# datetime format : can a computer be forced to use a particular format?

Tags: c#

I have developed a `winform` application that makes use of the format **`dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`** (24 hr system).

When I try the application on another computer, I get an **error**, because the `standard datetime` format there is **`dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm`**.

Moreover, the controls in which the datetime is **stored**, also hold the **datetime** string in a different format: **`d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm`**, eg **1/4/2013 12:00:00 A.M.** instead of **01/04/2013 12:00:00 A.M.**

Can I **force** the other system to somehow use the **same format**?
I am a novice here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: are you using `DateTime.ToString(stringformat)` already?

Comment: It's best, so far as possible, to work with `DateTime`s for as much as possible, and only deal with strings at the very outer edges of your application (e.g. the first thing to be done with input is to parse the string, the last thing to do with output is to format as a string). Not sure whether that's what you're dealing with or whether you're letting it hang around as a string for longer than necessary.

Comment: As other said.. do not force the system, force your application. Use always InvarianCulture, or adapt it to work with different formats based on the CurrentCulture

Answer (score 3):

When displaying a DateTime object, there are two things to keep in mind.

- [Culture settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx): when you don't specify an explicit culture, the culture that's set by the system your application is running on is used.
- [Format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx): when converting a DateTime object to a string, you can give it a format string as an argument that specifies how your DateTime object should be formatted. Something like: "d" for a short date pattern or "t" to only display the time.

Combining these two will give you full control over how to display your `DateTime` objects. You should however be careful in forcing a certain culture setting on the user. If your application should support globalization (so multiple users from different cultures can use your app) you shouldn't depend on a specific culture. Instead, you should store all your data culture-insensitive and format it with the users culture when you display it on screen.

Here is an example how to use both the CultureInfo object and a format string:

```
string myDate = "10-05-2013 08:52:30";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(myDate);

Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-US"))); // 5/10/2013
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("nl-NL"))); // 10-5-2013

Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("f", new CultureInfo("nl-NL"))); // vrijdag 10 mei 2013 08:52
```

Comment: I understand. Is there a culture that allows for display as 10-05-2013 instead of 10-5-2013.  Thanks.

Comment: Better yet, adapt your application to use the current culture, instead of forcing it to a fixed one. Especially if there is a UI (if a user choose that format, it is because he/she WANTS that format..)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the culture for the application to the one you need to use.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("EN");
```

Comment: I agree it might not be the best solution to force the application to one date and time.But that depends, if the application is only being used by dutch people for instance, it is not that bad. I've build some tools that only our developers use, and those are also forced into NL-culture.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to force the system to one date and time format. From my point of view the better question would be, why is your application using a specified format? The .NET Framework is designed that you don't have to care about such things.

Anyway, if you will really force the system to display the data in a specified format, change the thread culture:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
```